# Show that a certain function $\tilde{f}:S^3\to\mathbb{R}$ induces a function $f:S^3/S^1\to\mathbb{R}$ (group actions)

Tags: group-theory, quotient-spaces

I am a bit stuck on a homework assignment and I'm hoping someone can push me in the right direction.

Consider the 3-dimensional sphere:
$$S^3=\{(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{C}:|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2=1\}$$
and the circle $S^1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$, viewed as a group with respect to the multiplication of complex numbers. We consider the group action of $S^1$ on $S^3$ given by
$$z\cdot(z_1,z_2):=(zz_1,\bar{z}z_2).$$
Let $X:=S^3/S^1$. Consider $\tilde{f}:S^3\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$\tilde{f}(z_1,z_2):=z_1z_2+\bar{z}_1\bar{z}_2.$$
Show that $\tilde{f}$ induces a function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$.

My approach is to show that $\tilde{f}(x)=\tilde{f}(y)\iff\exists\gamma\in S^1:\gamma\cdot x=y\;\forall x,y\in S^3$, for then $\tilde{f}=f\circ\pi$, where $\pi$ is the surjection $\pi:S^3\to X$ that produces the quotient $S^3/S^1$.

The direct implication is simple: consider $(z_1,z_2),(w_1,w_2)\in S^3$ and let $\gamma\in S^1$ such that $w_1=\gamma z_1$ and $w_2=\bar{\gamma}z_2$. Then we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\tilde{f}(w_1,w_2)&=w_1w_2+\bar{w}_1\bar{w}_2\\
&=\gamma z_1\bar{\gamma}z_2+\overline{\gamma z_1}\overline{\bar{\gamma}z_2}\\
&=|\gamma|^2z_1z_2+|\gamma|^2\bar{z}_1\bar{z}_2\\
&=z_1z_2+\bar{z}_1\bar{z}_2.
\end{aligned}$$
Hence the required equality, however the converse got me stuck. I don't really see a way to acquire such a $\gamma$ from the equality $\tilde{f}(z_1,z_2)=\tilde{f}(w_1,w_2)$ and the few other properties. I've also tried assuming no such $\gamma$ exists and get to a contradiction, but I couldn't make that work either and got stuck pretty quickly.
Could anyone please give me a push in the right direction on how this can be shown? I'd appreciate that a lot! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You only need one direction of the implication. You need to make sure that the function behaves well with respect to the group action, i.e., $f(\gamma\cdot x)=f(x)$ for all $\gamma\in S^1$ and $x\in S^3$. To see that you don't need to worry about the other direction, consider $f\colon S^3\to \mathbb{R}$ a constant function. This will always descend to a function on the quotient.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand what you're saying. I have indeed shown that $f(\gamma\cdot x)=f(x)\;\forall\gamma\in S^1,\forall x\in S^3$, however why do I not need to worry about the other implication? The constant function $f:S^3\to\mathbb{R}$ is not a function $X\to\mathbb{R}$ that is induced by $\tilde{f}$, so I'm not sure how that helps me. I'm quite sure I must have a function that respects the quotient's equivalence relation, i.e. $f(x)=f(y)\iff\exists\gamma\in S^2:x=\gamma\cdot y$, because then I can use the composition and then it's also induced by $\tilde{f}$. Is my idea wrong?

Comment: What you have shown already implies that $\tilde{f}$ induces a map $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ on the quotient. I mentioned the function $\tilde{g}\colon S^3\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\tilde{g}(x)=0$ because this function does NOT satisfy the reverse implication but it does descend to a function $g\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ on the quotient.

Comment: Oh... But that makes me really confused. I still don't understand why what I did is sufficient. What if $\tilde{f}(x)=\tilde{f}(y)$, but $\not\exists\gamma\in S^1:\gamma\cdot x=y$? Wouldn't that run athwart with the definition of $\pi$ and the way $\tilde{f}$ induces $f$?

Comment: No, all that you need to push $\tilde{f}$ down to $X$ is that it is constant on the orbits of the action - since the orbits are the elements of $X$.

Comment: Oh, I see! Now it all makes perfect sense to me. Thanks a lot. This has solved everything and it has made me understand quotients by group actions a lot better.